# Why vars in Twig template hasn't values when in PHP they have

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

I have this code in my controller:

```
....
$sorted_entities[$stored_id][$stored_upc]["ent"] = $entity;
$sorted_entities[$stored_id][$stored_upc]["img"][] = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ProductBundle:ProductList')->findByImages($entity->getProductId(), $entity->getKCondition(), $this->getCompany(), $stored_upc);
....
```

If I debug `$sorted_entities` using this:

```
print "<pre>";
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($sorted_entities);
print "</pre>";
```

I get this as output:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["CI1A5VM38TGWD0AFPU84"]=>
    string(8) "Array(2)"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["DEFH50UEG43IWB2WEZ27"]=>
    string(8) "Array(2)"
  }
}
```

But if I do this in Twig template:

```
{% for iterator in entities %}
    {% set entity = iterator[iterator|keys[0]].0.ent %}
    {% set images = iterator[iterator|keys[0]].0.img %}
    {{ entity }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get no errors and no values, what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Try to use `entities[iterator]` instead of `iterator[iterator]`.

Comment: @n.1 doesn't work, nothing is showed

Comment: Does Twig return an error on the page or in the error log of the server? Is the [`keys` twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/keys.html) properly used?

Comment: @n.1 nope, in nowhere

Comment: Do you need to use complex strings as `$sorted_entities[$stored_id][$stored_upc]["img"]`? Can't you use something simpler like `$sorted_entities = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository([...]);`? You will still have access to the entity.